# Crontab inside a Bash file

Tags: django, bash, cron

I want to start my django project and execute every 10 min a BaseCommand. I wrote bash file it doesn't seem to work.
I have some cronjob code but I don't know if this is enough...

```
*/10 * * * * python3 manage.py read_create_earning_reports
```

...or activating the virtual environment for the crontab is neccessary.

```
*/10 * * * * cd /Users/andreysaykin/Documents/project_distrokid/project_dk && source ../bin/activate && python3 manage.py myBaseCommand
```

Afterwards I start my server.

```
cd /my/django/project/path
source ../bin/activate
python3 manage.py runserver
```

What my current Problem is that I am getting this Error:
`/Users/username/Documents/bash/myScript.sh: line 2: */10: No such file or directory`

Comment: The best practice and a standard solution for such a task is Celery + celery-beat: https://github.com/celery/django-celery-beat

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the absolute path to your python executable for the cronjob.

Assuming your project folder is in `$HOME/myproject` and the virtual enviroment is in $HOME/myproject/.venv/, the python executable you need is something like `$HOME/myproject/.venv/bin/python/`

You can also find it out by activating your virtual environment and typing in `which python`

The cronjob must then look something like this:

```
*/10 * * * * /Users/username/myproject/.venv/bin/python3 /Users/username/myproject/manage.py read_create_earning_reports
```

Comment: I tried your solution but I have the same error. It seems */10 will be registered as a file or directory.

Comment: How do you conclude that? Make sure that you also specify the absolute path to your manage.py file